# To find non-isomorphic subgroups of $G$

Tags: group-theory

Given G is a cyclic group of order $9$,Question asks to find the number of non-isomorphic subgroups of $G$.I am literally confused what exactly ask in question.Are they asking for the number of subgroups of $G$ which are non-isomorphic to $G$.Then since $G$ has exactly three subgroups of order $1,3,9$.Then subgroups of order $1,3$ must be non-isomorphic to $G$.So, I think answer is $2$.I have seen one related question asked on site and there it was given cyclic group of order $12$ and same question was asked.The answer given for that question says there are $6$ such subgroups but I got confused since $G$ is of course isomorphic to itself so remaining $5$ are non-isomorphic to $G$.Am I understanding question wrongly?

Comment: No, they just ask for subgroups which are pairwise non-isomorphic, including $G$.

Comment: They are asking to find the number of subgroups of $G$ that are pairwise non-isomorphic. So there are three: of orders $1$, $3$, and $9$.

Comment: what is pairwise non-isomorphic means?

Comment: Take any pair $U,V$ of subgroups. Then what could non-isomorphic mean for this pair?

Comment: @DietrichBurde..I am still confused about the term pairwise non-isomorphic .Means are we finding all possible pairs of subgroups of $G$ $(U,V)$ where $U,V$ are subgroups of $G$ and they are non-isomorphic to each other?

Comment: I have seen that question already as I mentioned in my question but I am not understanding what we are finding?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It means that $U$ and $V$ are not isomorphic to each other. We want to find all subgroups, but only up to isomorphism.

Comment: Ok ..then what about my reasoning mentioned in comment of your answer.I am understanding something wrong then.

Answer (score 0):

The question asks to find the number of non-isomorphic subgroups of $C_9$, and *not* the number of subgroups non-isomorphic to $C_9$. Now every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic itself. Since any two cyclic groups of the same order are isomorphic, and cyclic groups satisfy the converse of Lagrange's theorem, we indeed have for every divisor $d\mid 9$ exactly one subgroup up to isomorphism. So the answer is $\tau(9)=3$. And indeed, $\tau(12)=6$.

Comment: See in case of cyclic group of order 12 ,we have 6 subgroups of orders namely 1,2,3,4,6,12.So if we form pairs of two subgroups of different orders there will be 30 pairs ?I am not understanding what pairwise non-isomorphic subgroups ?

Comment: What is wrong in my above argument?

Comment: That's easy. For example, there may be several subgroups with $3$ elements. But they are all isomorphic to $C_3$. We only consider (pairwise) non-isomorphic subgroups, so we count all these subgroups of order $3$ as one.

Comment: I know it's irritating but my head is just getting spin.Last request to you.Can you show me that $6$ pairs you formed in case of order $12$.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, for any cyclic group of order $n$, every subgroup is cyclic, generated by some power of the generator. If $a$ denotes this generator, we know $a^k$ has order  $\dfrac n{n\wedge k}$,which is a divisor of $n$. Further, any two cyclic groups with the same order are isomorphic.

There results the number of non-isomorphic subgroups of a cyclic group of order $n$ is but the number of divisors of $n$.